# maven Local Repo version artifactory

Tags: maven-2, artifactory

How to differentiate between jars of same version present in local maven repo and artifactory.

Say for example sample-1.0.jar is present in local maven repository and also the same resides in artifactory but with latest code.

I need the jar(with latest code) from artifactory during maven build.(without clearing the local repo)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with -U command while making the build. This is for force updating the local repo. this may help you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do it. 
That's because the assumption is - you shouldn't have two different binaries under the same version (except of snapshots). Both Maven and Artifactory operate under this assumption and there is no way to override it.

**Bottom line:**

1. Don't have different binaries under same version.
2. the only way is to clean local repo (you might of a maven plugin to do that if you can't fix the problem with conflicting binaries).